# How to add un/archive or un/trash buttons in a manager button-group that isn't in a dropdown?

Tags: component, jhtml

What I'm trying to do is this:

[image]

But failing at it.
The codes I've tried using are:

```
<td class="nowrap center">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <?php echo JHtml::_('jgrid.published', $row->state, $i, 'records.', true, 'cb'); ?>
        <?php echo JHtml::_('jgrid.published', ((int) $row->state === 2 ? 1 : 2), $i, 'records.', true, true, 'cb'); ?>
        <?php echo JHtml::_('jgrid.published', ((int) $row->state === -2 ? 1 : -2), $i, 'records.', true, true, 'cb'); ?>
    </div>
</td>
```

and also an attempt at:

```
<td class="nowrap center">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <?php echo JHtml::_('jgrid.published', $row->state, $i, 'records.', true, 'cb'); ?>
        <?php echo JHtml::_('jgrid.state', JHtml::_('grid.publishedOptions'), ((int) $row->state === 2 ? 1 : 2), $i, 'records.', true, true, 'cb'); ?>
        <?php echo JHtml::_('jgrid.state', JHtml::_('grid.publishedOptions'), ((int) $row->state === -2 ? 1 : -2), $i, 'records.', true, true, 'cb'); ?>
    </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to look into this again and I seem to have found a solution.

Just like the publish button rendered using `jgrid.published` in the example below:

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('jgrid.published', $row->state, $i, 'myitems.', true, 'cb', $row->publish_up, $row->publish_down); ?>
```

Use the more general purpose `jgrid.action` render instead, which is defined in the joomla library as:

```
public static function action($i, $task, $prefix = '', $text = '', $active_title = '', $inactive_title = '', $tip = false, $active_class = '',
    $inactive_class = '', $enabled = true, $translate = true, $checkbox = 'cb')
```

Although unlike `jgrid.published`, this renderer creates buttons with a singular fixed task. It isn't state-aware, i.e. it cannot automatically assign a task based on the current state. But one could always mimic that behaviour by using an `if-else` code-wrapper to control which buttons to show.